# How to implemented push notification to java client

Tags: java, push-notification

I'm building a java stand alone application. This application is installed on one pc. There is another java stand alone program that it is installed in another pc to another net.

Now I want to send a notification with these program. For example the program 1, send message "start update", and the program 2 read this message and can execute an activity.

Now how can I implemented this push notification.
I have also a php server, I don't know if this server is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little strange question... you can use lot of technologies e.g. Rest, JMS, but also *ugh* you can send UDP packets or use a pipe on file system. It depends to what you have to send, for which purpose, with which security level.

Comment: I want to sent only message from this two program. For exmaple the program one send at program two, this message: "downlaod all data", the program two activate your method.

Comment: If you google a little, you find lot of interesting choices ;) E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615958/make-a-client-server-java-application